# I am trying to make UL li based good CSS menus and having positioning problem

Tags: css, menu, position, positioning

I am trying to make UL li based good CSS menus and having positioning problem. They are not getting positioned as i wanted. They get out of div i put them in. How to fix this problem ?

Comment: Let me consult with `The Oracle`. Or you could just provide some code.

Comment: Please post your HTML/CSS so we can have a look at it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am guessing that you are having problem with browsers auto margin feature.

Use this to reset their margin feature before starting menus.

```
* {
    margin : 0;
    padding : 0;
}
```

Comment: How on earth did you understand the issue from the question? Amazing - like you're a mind reader! +1 for interpreting a question with nearly no information!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what the issue is as you have not posted your HTML, CSS or even a link to [jsfiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net/) ...

However, I do remember the when I was a newby and I also had troubles with CSS Menus.

I highly recommend you take the time to check out "Son of Suckerfish Dropdowns":

**http://www.htmldog.com/articles/suckerfish/dropdowns/**

I think you will find it very helpful.